# Front controller redirection works but the route is wrong for some routes

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, model-view-controller, front-controller

I've been wrapping my head around this problem for the whole day and nothing seems to work so far. I admit that it can be a really lame problem but I can't even explain it exactly at the moment, but I'll try and look forward to get some help!

I have an MVC site with Front Controller. All requests are being redirected to `index.php` and depends on the URI (which I made user-friendly using a special array with routes) my Front Controller calls for the right Controller. Standard routeing. And basically it's working fine. Except one nuance.

My `.htaccess` file consists of these:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /portfolio/test/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

this is the example of the routes I use for user-friendly URLs and to call corresponding controllers:

```
    <?php

return array (
  'main'               => 'index/main', //actionMain in IndexController
  'contact'            => 'contact/index', 
  'prise'              => 'price/index',  
  'blog/([0-9]+)'      => 'blog/post/$1',  
  'blog'               => 'blog/list',
   etc...       
);
```

If I go to the `/main` page it's all good, then I click on the link with `/portfolio` and it's all good as well.

By the way my navigation is made automatically using array with 'slug' and 'name' for menu buttons. So in `nav.php` I take an array with slugs and names like this:

```
<?php

    $navItems = array(

         array(
            'slug'            => "main",
            'title'           => "Main"
            ),

         array(
            'slug'            => "portfolio",
            'title'           => "Portfolio"
            ),

        array(
            'slug'            => "prise",
            'title'           => "Prise List"
            ),

        etc...

    );

    ?>
```

I use `foreach` for this array and make buttons automatically like this:

```
echo "<a href=\"$Item[slug]\">"
```

But the problem occurs when I go to `blog/{some_article}` (e.g. `blog/1`) or directly put `blog/` into the address field after my base path (which is `www.example.com/porfolio/test/`). And it seems that the problem is not in the redirection because the right controller is called and even data from my database is here. The problem occurs in HTML link tags and automatically made hyperlinks in navigation. Now they see the base path as `www.example.com/porfolio/test/blog/{some article}` so the path to the files is wrong now so I don't see my styles and pictures. I need to somehow get rid of this `blog/{some article}` part for the base root but still see it in the address bar or at least understand where is the problem hiding.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem occurs in HTML link tags and automatically made hyperlinks in navigation. Now they see the base path as `www.example.com/porfolio/test/blog/{some article}` so the path to the files is wrong now so I don't see my styles and pictures.

This sounds like a client-side relative path "problem". If you are using relative URLs to your styles and pictures the URLs are now relative to `/porfolio/test/blog/`, not `/porfolio/test/`.

You need to either use absolute or root-relative (starting with a slash) URLs in your client-side HTML, or use the `base` tag in the `head` section, informing the browser what these relative paths are *relative* to.

See my answer on the Pro Webmasters Stack for details:
[.htaccess rewrite url leads to missing css](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243)